# How to clear pending message from azure service bus?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-servicebus-queues

I am using azure service bus for receiving message to processing my background process. In my background process I want to clear already processed messages from azure service bus. Is there any way or method to clear azure service bus messages???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [How to receive messages from a queue](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/) and make sure you use `_queueClient.Complete()` or `_queueClient.Abandon()` to finish with each message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging" and purge messages by en-queue time. Receive the messages, filter by ScheduledEnqueueTime and perform purge when the message has been en-queued at the specific time.

```
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

MessagingFactory messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

var queueClient = messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient(resourceName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);

var client = messagingFactory.CreateMessageReceiver(resourceName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);

BrokeredMessage message = client.Receive();

if (message.EnqueuedTimeUtc < MessageEnqueuedDateTime)
{
    message.Complete(); 
}
```